# delete tab at the beginning of export CSV file

Tags: php, csv

When I generate an export to a CSV file, I have a tab that is inserted at the beginning.

I don't understand why.

Here is my code :

```
public function hookExportAll($params){


        header('Content-Type: application/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="clients.csv"');
        header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');

        //mysql request
        $sql = "..."
        $clientlist = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);

                    //separator recovered the post of the form 
        $filter['sep']=Tools::getValue('sep');
        //; or , or \t

        $entete = array('email','nom','prenom','anniversaire','newsletter','adresse','pays','téléphone');

        echo $this->getcsvline($entete, $sep);

        foreach($clientlist AS $client){
            echo $this->getcsvline($client, $sep);
        }

}

private function getcsvline($list, $sep="\t"){  
    return implode($sep, $list)."\r\n";
}
```

A little help?

Comment: The problem is unlikely to be anything to do with your database code.  Please simplify your code snippet to the **minimum** necessary to cause the problem (see http://sscce.org/).  Thanks.

Comment: Just a general comment on your code... You probably shouldn't output your MIME headers so early - if anything goes wrong with your DB query etc you have no way of outputting a meaningful error in HTML, etc. You'd be better served to wait on sending the headers until you are sure you have the data available to send as a csv.

Comment: I don't see where you are assigning a value to your `$sep` variable. Is there supposed to be a line `$sep = $filter['sep']` ?

Comment: Could it be that the tabs origin is outside of this scope? Perhaps you should take a look at what happens before the <?php-tag?

Comment: Yes, when I simplify my code, I delete this part :

switch(Tools::getValue('sep')){
    case 2:
     $sep=';';
     break;
    case 1:
     $sep=',';
     break;
    case 0:
    default:
     $sep="\t";
     break;
   }

Comment: @Ivar Bonsaksen : This is a module that inherits from a model which itself inherits from several models. My csv export is a module for prestashop. I do not know if it is possible that a tab will be inserted before my php tag. In my file in any case, it is not the case.

I tried to trim, rtrim, but nothing happens.

In the end, I am not sure to find a real answer to my question.

Comment: Try to add `die('-');` at the very beginning of your `hookExportAll()`-method. If the output still includes a tab before the `-`, you should take a look at what happens outside your method call. Anything written outside `<?php ?>` will be output directly.

Comment: the tab is added before the "-". There must be effectively generated a tab ... I will try to find out where the problem, but it may be tedious.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, Ivar Bonsaksen must be right. A tab must have been generated in the CMS Prestashop before a . With no time to dwell on this case, I consider this issue as resolved.

Thank you all for your support, see you soon =)